# Reference Request: KKT in Hilbert Space

Tags: optimization, hilbert-spaces, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Are there analogues of Slater's condition and the KKT conditions in separable Hilbert spaces?  Does the infinite dimensionality pose a problem?

Comment: Certainly - a couple good references are the book "Convex Analysis and Variational Problems" by Ekeland and Temam (Thm 5.1) and "Nonlinear Functional Analysis III" by Zeidler (The whole book, but specifically Section 47.10).  Things are, of course, more complicated, but analogies definitely exist.

Comment: I'll take a look here as well :)  Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Variational Analysis in Sobolev and BV Spaces: Applications to PDEs and Optimization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898716004). It deals with Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions in normed spaces which is more general than Hilbert spaces.

You may find it interesting too [An ε-lagrange multiplier rule for a mathematical programming problem on banacch spaces](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02331930108844524) and their references.

Comment: This is perfect!  Thanks so much!